# Perl - regular expressions first occurrence of group

Tags: regex, perl

I am matching a line against a pattern, something like:

```
if (/.*someRegExp(.*)someOtherRegExp.*/)
{
process $1
}
```

but, the problem is that I have, in the line, many occurrences of "someRegExp(.*)someOtherRegExp"

Can you please tell me how can I select, for sure!, the first occurrence?

thank you!

Comment: Try: `/someRegExp(.*?)someOtherRegExp/`. Don't use `.*` or `.*?` unless you're capturing their matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make your quantifiers not greedy. `*` is greedy by default, which means it tries to capture as much as possible.  To make it not greedy, add `?`:

```
if (/.*?someRegExp(.*?)someOtherRegExp.*?/)
{
    process $1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make your quantifier reluctant before that part of regex:

```
if (/.*?someRegExp(.*)someOtherRegExp.*/)
{
    process $1
}
```

Now, `.*?` will only match the string before the first substring matching the pattern following it.

Comment: Is 'reluctant' the actual term?

Comment: @NathanFellman. Yes it is another name for [Lazy quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html). Read para under the heading **Laziness Instead of Greediness** in that link.

Comment: I'll have to upvote if only because I learned something new today :-)